# acces to array outside an ajax call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to use the data from an array called struct, I'm calling the data from an ajax but then I don't know how to use it, look:

```
var raw_data = null;
$.ajax({
    url:path.url_respuesta_leer, async:false,
    type:"post", dataType:"json", data:{form:id},
    success : function(obj) {
        var raw_data = obj.struct;
    }
    //console.log(raw_data) show: [Object, Object, Object] 0:Object label:"Some text"
});

var new_data = [ {"Title": raw_data[0].label } , etc...
```

Console says that is undefined. I know it's simple, but I can't get it. Help please.

Comment: You can't. Put the usage code inside the callback.

Comment: Duplicate? with the answer below I could do it, was a mistake on double defining the var. So it's not duplicate.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the `async: false` you mixed in there. True, that doesn't make it a duplicate then, merely a typo. **However**, you *should* make this asynchronous and use the callback. Synchronous AJAX requests are a bad idea, as they're blocking your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't refine that same variable again inside the ajax success block where you store the data.

```
var raw_data = null; // this should be only one.
$.ajax({
    url:path.url_respuesta_leer, async:false,
    type:"post", dataType:"json", data:{form:id},
    success : function(obj) {
        //var raw_data = obj.struct; don't use 'var'
        raw_data = obj.struct;
    }
    //console.log(raw_data) show: [Object, Object, Object] 0:Object label:"Some text"
});

var new_data = [ {"Title": raw_data[0].label }
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to delete the "var" on the 2nd raw_data, because I wasn't defining it above in a previous version.